# WordPress site taking too long to load after migrating to remote database

Tags: php, wordpress, database-migration

I have a WordPress site running on Digital Ocean droplet with MySQL database on the same server. I am trying to migrate the database to a remote database. I used Digital Ocean's managed SQL service in the same region for it, but after changing the database configuration in `wp-config.php`, the site is taking 30+ seconds to load now.

I also tried using the GCP's Cloud SQL but facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first confirming if you can reach the remote SQL server on your own and what's the response time from the other server.

If everything seems fine and both servers are in the same region, ask DigitalOcean if it's possible for the two servers to communicate in the private network instead of connecting through public  IPs.

Finally, if you are still experiencing this issue, I would suggest reaching their support and explaining this issue. They should be able to help if it's a "managed" service.